# Find duplicates for combination of two columns in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, select, count, duplicates, distinct

I work on a dataset with three different columns: `pile`, `position` and `info`.

There is no duplicate in the database, but it can happen, that for one combination of `pile` and `position` there is one or two different texts in the info column. And those are the entries I tried to find.

I tried the following

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`pile`, `position`)) FROM db;
```

But received an error message

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Is there a way to find distinct combinations of values in two columns?

Comment: try this **SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`pile`+`position`)) FROM db;**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works even without subselects.

```
SELECT
  `pile`,
  `position`,
  COUNT(*) AS c
FROM
  db
GROUP BY
  `pile`,
  `position`
HAVING c > 1;
```

The command above shows all combinations of `pile` and `position` that occur more than once in the table `db`.

Comment: It has never been so easy to get duplicates. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of distinct duplicates (group by used in preference here)

```
   select count(*)
     from (
   select pile, position
     from db
 group by pile, position
          ) x
```

To find the actual duplicate records

```
   select db.*
     from (
   select pile, position
     from db
 group by pile, position
   having count(*) > 1
          ) x
     join db on db.pile = x.pile and db.position = x.position
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM db x
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM db y
  WHERE y.pile = x.pile
  AND y.position =x.postion
  AND y.other_field <> x.other_field
  );
```

Now, for `other_field` you can use some unique id column, or any combination of fields (except for {pole, postion} of course)